Reverse for 'listing_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['listings/listings/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
I'm new to django and I'm creating a listing site, similar to Gumtree.  When I try to retrieve the logged-in user's listings from the database and display on their MyListings page, I get the above error.  My code is below.  Any help would be appreciated!
Also, I have checked, each listing has a pk value.
urls.py
from django.urls import path
from listings import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('my_listings/', views.my_listings, name='my_listings'),
    path('create/', views.create_listing, name='create_listing'),
    path('listings/<int:pk>/', views.listing_detail, name='listing_detail'),
    path('listings/<int:pk>/update/', views.update_listing, name='update_listing'),
    path('listings/<int:pk>/delete/', views.delete_listing, name='delete_listing'),
]

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Listing
from users.models import Profile
from .forms import ListingForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

User = get_user_model()

@login_required
def my_listings(request):
    print("my_listings view called")
    context = {} #initialise the context dictionary
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        try:
             # Get logged-in user
            logged_in_user=request.user
            # Get user profile
            profile=get_object_or_404(Profile, email=logged_in_user.email)
            print(f"Profile for user {request.user}: {profile}")
            listings = Listing.objects.filter(profile=profile)
            print(f"Listings for profile {profile}: {listings}")

            for listing in listings:
                print(f"Listing PK: {listing.pk}")

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print(f"Profile does not exist for user {request.user}")
            # If the profile doesn't exist, handle the error
            profile = None
            listings = Listing.objects.none()

        context['listings'] = listings
        print("Context listings:", listings)
        
        return render(request, "my_listings.html", context)
    else:
        # If user not logged-in, redirect to login page
        return redirect('login')

my_listings.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% url 'create_listing' as create_listing_url %}
{% url 'listing_detail' as listing_detail_url %}
{% url 'update_listing' as update_listing_url %}
{% url 'delete_listing' as delete_listing_url %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="dj-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 offset-md-2">
                <h1>MyListings</h1>
                {% if listings %}
                    <ul>
                        {% for listing in listings %}
                            <div class="listing">
                                <li>{{ listing.title }}</li>
                                <p>PK: {{ listing.pk }}</p>
                                <!-- Debug print statement to check listing PK -->
                                {% if listing.pk %}
                                    <p>Listing PK: {{ listing.pk }}</p>
                                {% else %}
                                    <p>Listing PK is empty or None</p>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    <p>
                        <a href="{% url 'listing_detail' pk=listing.pk %}">View Details</a>
                        <a href="{% url 'update_listing' pk=listing.pk %}">Update Listing</a>
                        <a href="{% url 'delete_listing' pk=listing.pk %}">Delete Listing</a>
                    </p>
                {% else %}
                    <p>No listings yet - <a href="{% url 'create_listing' %}">create your first listing here</a>!</p>
                {% endif %}

                {% if listings %}
                    <p><a href="{% url 'create_listing' %}">Create Listing</a></p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}



The listing pk is none or actually its outside of the for loop so listing is probably none

Thanks Sayse, it was needing to move the hrefs into the loop. That's given me a base to build on.  Much appreciated!
